# Does apple pages sharing strictly require an iCloud account?

Tags: email, pages, sharing

My client is attempting to share (via an email address) a Pages document.

I walked him through using his iCloud account to do this, which worked.

However, his first choice would be to have the file come from his business email. Is this possible with Pages?

Comment: I would think it woud use whatever email address is the default one on the device.  Have you tried that?  Or are you saying he wants to be able to choose which email address to use?

Comment: You mean share as in both people can edit in sync, or just 'give a copy'?

Comment: @Tetsujin That should be "give a copy" (using email, specifically)

Comment: @fsb Definitely it should be his choice of email, even if that is different from his Apple ID. Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac, it's -

Share menu > Send a Copy > Mail

on iOS -

Ellipsis menu > Share > Mail

In either case, the choice of email account is set from within the mailer software, before sending.

Comment: Okay. That's good to know. I will have to go to his office to troubleshoot it as a Mail problem then. I thank all of you.